# Immutable data structures with path-dependent types in Scala

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, immutability, type-level-computation

I've written an implementation of a directed graph in Scala, which uses path dependent types to enforce the invariant that edges may only be created between nodes of the same graph:

```
package uk.co.timcowlishaw.BayTree;
import scala.collection.IndexedSeq;
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector;

sealed trait Graph[T] {
  type Self
  def addVertex(value : T) : Vertex[T, Self];
  def addEdge(source : Vertex[T, Self], destination : Vertex[T, Self]) : Edge[T, Self];
}


sealed trait Vertex[T, G] {
  def value : T;
}

sealed trait Edge[T, G] {
  def source : Vertex[T, G];
  def destination : Vertex[T, G];
}


object Graph {

  type TwoDimensional[M[_], X] = M[M[X]];

  type AdjacencyMatrix = TwoDimensional[IndexedSeq, Boolean];

  def apply[T] : Graph[T] = new GraphImpl[T]();

  private case class GraphImpl[T] extends Graph[T] {
    type Self = this.type

    private case class VertexImpl(val value : T) extends Vertex[T, Self]

    private case class EdgeImpl(
      val source : Vertex[T, Self],
      val destination : Vertex[T, Self]
    ) extends Edge[T, Self]

    private var vertices = Vector[VertexImpl]()
    private var adjacency = Vector.fill(0,0)(false)

    def addVertex(value : T) : Vertex[T, Self] = {
      val vertex = VertexImpl(value)
      vertices = vertices :+ vertex
      adjacency = adjacency.map(_ :+ false) :+ Vector.fill(vertices.length)(false)
      return vertex
    }

    def addEdge(source : Vertex[T, Self], destination : Vertex[T, Self]) : Edge[T, Self] = {
      val edge = EdgeImpl(source, destination)
      val adj = adjacency(vertices.indexOf(source))
      adjacency = adjacency.updated(vertices.indexOf(source), adj.updated(vertices.indexOf(destination), true))
      return edge
    }
  }
}
```

The instances of `GraphImpl` here are mutable, as adding a new node or edge mutates the vertex list and/or the adjacency matrix.

I'd like to adapt this to produce an immutable implementation. As far as I can see, this would involve adapting the `addVertex` and `addEdge` methods of the `Graph` trait to return a tuple (Graph, Vertex) or (Graph, Edge) where the first element of the tuple is the updated Graph object. However, trying to specify this return type, I run into problems:

```
sealed trait Graph[T] {
  type Self
  def addVertex(value : T) : (Graph[T], Vertex[T, ???]);
  def addEdge(source : Vertex[T, Self], destination : Vertex[T, Self]) : (Graph[T], Edge[T, ???]);
}
```

Fairly obviously, the second type parameter of the returned `Vertex` or `Edge` should be the `Self` member of the returned `Graph` (and not the `Self` member of the target of the method call). I can't for the life of me work out how to express this in the type signature (as I don't have a reference to the returned graph in order to express this type). Can anyone think of a way to express this, or, failing that, another way to enforce the same invariants at compile time for an immutable `Graph` type?

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are hitting a very common problem. See for example http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/02/when-oo-and-fp-meet-mytype-problem.html or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-debate/HYqlgzNshyo/i4LJY90_cVwJ